# Weird behaviour of FragmentStateAdapter in ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, view, fragment, adapter

dears.

I'm using **ViewPager2** & **FragmentStateAdapter** to add Fragments dynamically. And I stuck for 1 week already. Read all data here but no topics regarding my question.

I'll simplify real project just to illustrate my issue.

1. I have **HostFragment** which fills full screen in MainActivity.
2. HostFragment has **ViewPager2** which fills full screen of HostFragment.
3. Tapping on the FAB new **PageFragment** should be created in ViewPager2 and *immediately after it* some View should be inflated on just created page.

How I'd realize it:

```
class HostFragment : Fragment() {

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            _viewPager = binding.viewPager
----------------------------------
// For now viewModel.pages is empty - MutableList<PageFragment>()
----------------------------------
            _viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerHostFragmentAdapter(this, viewModel.pages)
            viewPager.adapter = viewPagerAdapter

            viewModel.pages.add(PageFragment())
            viewPagerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(viewModel.pages.size - 1)
----------------------------------
// Retrieving the PageFragment on which some View will be inflated.
// For now there are 1 Fragment in viewModel.pages
----------------------------------

            var page = viewModel.pages.last()

            val inflater =
            LayoutInflater.from(page.requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.some_view, null, false)
            page.binding.addView(inflater)
}
```

Normally **notifyItemInserted** triggers fun **createFragment** in adapter. Adapter checks if fragment isn't already created and creates new instanse of fragment. So after **notifyItemInserted** immediately should be launched **createFragment -> creation methods in PageFragment (onAttach, OnCreate so on...).** And only after it the rest of code in **HostFragment** should be executed.

But this isn't happen. After `viewPagerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(viewModel.pages.size - 1)` the rest of code is executed:

```
                var page = viewModel.pages.last()
    
                val inflater =
                LayoutInflater.from(page.requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.some_view, null, false)
                page.binding.addView(inflater)
```

And when it comes to `LayoutInflater.from(page.requireContext())...` app crashes with
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PageFragment{c44e369} (a42d8521-35ae-4bb4-b445-c126e06fe026) **not attached to a context.***

It's clear. Because PageFragment **isn't created yet**, and we try to make some actions with it. In this case we try to inflate View on it.

I checked. If to remove

```
                var page = viewModel.pages.last()
    
                val inflater =
                LayoutInflater.from(page.requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.some_view, null, false)
                page.binding.addView(inflater)
```

then **createFragment -> creation methods in PageFragment (onAttach, OnCreate so on...)** is executed after **notifyItemInserted**

It's weird for me. It brakes foundomental rule of code order execution. **Every line of code should be executed only after the previous line is done.**

In this case app somehow skips **notifyItemInserted** and say: "*Hey, friend. I'll execute it later*". And goes to execute the rest of code. And only after it's done, app says: "*Ok. Let's come back and execute all logic connected with **notifyItemInserted***". Means **createFragment -> creation methods in PageFragment (onAttach, OnCreate so on...)**

**How can I force the app execute all methods sequentially?** So no code is executed before **notifyItemInserted -> createFragment -> onAttach, OnCreate so on** is done?

How can I force the rest of code to wait till **notifyItemInserted** and all connected methods with it are done?

#### I need PageFragment to be created before app starts to inflate Views on it.

---

P.S.

1. I tried to debug **notifyItemInserted** and see what is does under the hood. But after few layers of repeats it comes to **C++** code which compiler can't reach.
2. I am sure that **notifyItemInserted** triggers **createFragment**. Because if to remove rest of code with View inflation, the fragment is created perfectly. And if then to remove **notifyItemInserted**, fragment is added to **viewModel.pages** but is not inflated in the screen. *Conclusion:* **notifyItemInserted** triggers **createFragment**.
3. **setCurrentItemView** doesn't matter here. Even without it the **notifyItemInserted** sets created fragment on the screen. *If the rest of code is absent of course.*
4. Yes, I can execute inflations of Views inside **onViewCreated** of **PageFragment**. So we'll always be sure that Views are created only after the page in created. But I want to inflate View from HostFragment. Some another reasons for it exist, which are out of my question context.

Comment: About your second point - as you've noticed `notifyItemInserted` creates the fragment but you've missed the fact that it happens during next main cycle. For that simple fact it's impossible to "wait" for it to happen in `onViewCreated` that's being executed on main thread. You have to abandon your idea of violating fragments lifecycle with view injection and respect it as you've noticed in point 4.

Comment: Dear Pawel, thank you for the comment. I'll try it accordingly point 4. 
Didin't know anything about "main cycle". Going to read.